# What is the maximum yield of apple tree?

Tags: trees, fertilizer, planting, apples

I am in the plan to plant and grow some apple trees in my land in kashmir. I want to know answers for the following questions.

1. How to plant it in proper manner?
2. what is the method of weeding it?
3. What is the yield can i have from apple trees?
4. When should i water the trees?
5. How much amount fertilizers i need to apply to the trees?

Comment: You need to ask separate questions. You also need to specify your climate, soil type and anything else that might help.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is asking too many questions without enough detail, and will likely be put [on hold](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). The best thing is to pick a type of apple tree you like, then ask different questions about care and yield. Thanks for taking our tour! The [help] will teach you about the site. [Ask] is a good starting page. Looking at some of the questions in the tags you've used is also good, in case there's already some information you need. We hope you stay here and have fun!